# Nested Form Alternative

Tags: html, forms, nested

i doing some shopping cart ui in html. 
I would like to avoid nested form but any solution which allow me to route request to two different handler is preferable with the data included. There are two requests are delete item and check out.

I wonder what is the alternative solution to nested form.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have nested forms in HTML, so you have to use an alternative.

The form that you post doesn't have to be located where the information that you want to post is located. You can use Javascript to copy the information from some fields in the page into hidden fields inside a form somewhere else on the page, and post that form.

This will also make the page simpler. You can use a single form for the delete function, instead of having one form for each item.